# How do I compile all my .js files into one minified file using grunt?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm new to grunt and I need a little help setting it up.  I want to use SASS, Compass and compile all my .js files into one minified file.

The site I'm working on is not currently using grunt and I want to set it up to use it.  All my .js files are included at the bottom of the page.  What do I need to do to change it so that only one minified .js file contains all of the .js files?

At the bottom of my index page I have .js files included like so:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular-route.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.4/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/src/loading-bar.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-promise-tracker/promise-tracker.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-promise-tracker/promise-tracker-http-interceptor.js"></script>
<script src="js/config.json" type="application/json"></script>
<script src="js/infinite-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/hotels.js"></script>
<script src="js/weather.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

My Gruntfile.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        minified : {
          files: {
            src: [
              '/js/src/**/*.js',                
              '/js/src/*.js'
            ],
            dest: '/js/min/'
          }
        },      

        compass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    sassDir: 'sass',
                    cssDir: 'css'
                }
            }
        },

        watch: {
            css: {
                files: '**/*.scss',
                tasks: ['compass']
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-minified');
    grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
}
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "hoteldemo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.0.3",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to use something like [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin). It may even be worth your time to explore some of the generators provided by [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) since these generally give you the proper grunt scaffolding depending on the technologies you're using.

Using `grunt-usemin` alone in your project would look something like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular-route.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.4/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- build:js js/min/app.min.js -->
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/src/loading-bar.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-promise-tracker/promise-tracker.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-promise-tracker/promise-tracker-http-interceptor.js"></script>
<script src="js/config.json" type="application/json"></script>
<script src="js/infinite-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/hotels.js"></script>
<script src="js/weather.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

You'll have to configure a grunt task to do the build for you which will be pretty specific to your setup. Just follow along with the [grunt-usemin documentation](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin).

Comment: That looks like what I'm looking for.  In your example though wouldn't I just need to include `js/min/app.min.js` on the page?   The configuration shows this as the destination file and the included files as the source files so I don't see what I would need to include both on the page.  Sorry if I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: Usemin would add a script with the src `js/min/app.min.js` in place of the usemin block in a new output html file.